# How to use visual studio code to debug a Python & C++ program?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I've looked up video tutorials on this that seems to focus just on how to debug a single file.

I'm running a simulation code that probably goes through 100s different python and C++ source files. There's a particular spot in a python function that I want to set a breakpoint for. I have set the breakpoint.

I usually run the simulation code with

```
python3 path/to/sim/directory path/to/input
```

How can I use this command with the debugger in VSC?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899347/how-do-i-debug-a-cli-with-vscode

Answer (score 0):

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more information.

First select the Run view in the sidebar:

[image]

If you don't yet have any configurations defined, you'll see a button to Run and Debug and a link to create a configuration (launch.json) file:

[image]

To generate a file with Python configurations, do the following steps:

Select the create a `launch.json` file link (outlined in the image above) or use the **Run** > **Open configurations menu command**.

A configuration menu will open from the Command Palette allowing you to choose the type of debug configuration you want for the opened file. For now, in the Select a debug configuration menu that appears, select **Python File**.

[image]

Then you can use debug mode to run python file.

[image]